# How to replacement collect match word?

Tags: r, gsub

I want change perfect match one word.

Only "x" change to "x1"

Using `gsub()`, however, all words include "x" change.

How can I do?

```
temp=c("x", "xx", "xxx")  
gsub("x", "x1", temp)
("x1", "x1x1", "x1x1x1")
# I want below product
("x1", "xx", "xxx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `^` and `$` at start and end of the string respectively

```
sub("^x$", "x1", temp)
#[1] "x1"  "xx"  "xxx"
```

but since this is an exact match why not use `==` for comparison?

```
temp[temp == "x"] <- "x1"
```

Comment: Thank you. I use ^, $. and "==" is don't know. but, i learn to new one. thanks again.